# Meteor Upgrade to 1.2.0.2 from 1.1.x

Tags: meteor

I'm running into the below issues when I upgraded my meteor project from 1.1.6 to 1.2.0.2:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleSchema is not defined Uncaught
> ReferenceError: AccountsTemplates is not defined Uncaught
> ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined Uncaught ReferenceError:
> Template is not defined
```

It is successful project deployed using 1.1.6

I'm not sure how to fix this, please suggest.

Thanks.

The below is my packages files:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library
logging
reload
random
ejson
check
standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

underscore
iron:router
spacebars
less
materialize:materialize
useraccounts:materialize
useraccounts:core
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
gildaspk:autoform-materialize
accounts-password
alethes:pages
matb33:collection-hooks
alanning:roles
meteorhacks:aggregate
momentjs:moment
pcel:serialize
pcel:loading

aldeed:simple-schema
digilord:faker
meteorhacks:kadira

useraccounts:flow-routing
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting? No need to use both 4 spaces and `>`. Just paste the contents of `.meteor/packages`, select the text, and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: I just did because it is easy to understand for the readers, in my packages file they are not there it is a simple txt file which I've not created/edited.
Anyways, I've pasted it as you asked. Thanks.